# Custom adapter replaces old items when adding new

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I have a problem with my custom list adapter.
My main activity consist of a ListView, Button and a EditText field.
When the user inputs something in the EditText field, and presses the button. The text should
appear in the ListView. For the ListView i have made a custom adapter. That at the moment only consist of a TextView, but i will later add more stuff so i can not use a standard adapter.

The problem is that when the user types something, and presses the button, the string is placed in the ListView, (great!), but the problem is when the user presses again, that the old text is replaced by the new (the list has 2 items, both contain same text). When the user adds a third item to the list, this item replaces the old ones, and i now have 3 of the newest in the list?

So the problem is that the newest item replaces the old ones?

In my mainActivity i have this:

```
private ListView list_messages;
private Button send_button;
private TextView input_message;

public Custome_list_item adapter;
public ArrayList<String> message_holder;

message_holder = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new Custome_list_item(this,message_holder);
list_messages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The custom list adapter only has a getView, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);

TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_in_list_row);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile);
TextView timeView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date_and_time);

txtTitle.setText(message_holder.get(message_holder.size()-1));

//imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
timeView.setText("DD:MM:YY");
return rowView;
```

when the user clicks the button in the main activity, i do this:

```
mainActivity.message_holder.add(item);

mainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getview is using size in the .get function, so it will always return the last string in the array as the text.  It should be using the position passed in to the call.

Comment: Because getView will be called for every visible index of the ListView.  The purpose of the function is to fill in the data for that view when the screen refreshes (due to invalidate, scrolling, or notifyDataSetChanged).

Comment: By the way, your getView function should check if the view passed in (the convertView) is null or not.  If non-null, you shouldn't inflate a new one, instead you should just fill in the data (the view can be reused, and should be for efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
txtTitle.setText(message_holder.get(message_holder.size()-1));
```

to

```
txtTitle.setText(message_holder.get(position));
```

Because `position` will replace the view's position to the item,i.e. On first item the `txtTitle` from first adapter position will be displayed.On second listItem the second Adapter View will be displayed and so on.

Comment: @user3741818 Happy to help,Enjoy coding.